# Git can I make multiple commits on one file before submitting or pushing and deploying?

Tags: git

Not finding the answer to this question.  If I have a file and I make changes to it.  I add and commit those changes.  Before I push/deploy the commit, I'm asked to make more changes to the same file (separate from the first changes).  Can I make the added changes, add and commit them, then push/deploy?  Or will that cause me problems?

Comment: If the changes belong to one task, then make them as one commit. If they are for several tasks, then make a commit for each task.

Comment: Note, by the way, that every commit makes a copy of *every* file. You don't really commit just one file. Fortunately, a bunch of commits that all share the same copy of `README.md` and `doc.txt` and so on for 25000 files, quite literally *share* the same copy of all the files. Only files that are different have to be saved again in their new, different form. But it's important to remember that every commit is a complete, standalone copy of every file, at least in principle.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you may do as many commits as you want.

Ideally each commit should be a single logical change, regardless of the number of affected files.

If you want you may event `git add` a fragment of a file - use `git add -p` and select which parts you want to commit.

`git push` pushes all your changes to the current branch.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Though, the question is a bit ambigous.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all! There is no problem making multiple commits on the same file before pushing your changes to the repository.

Comment: Thank, you!!  I thought it was okay, but wanted to be sure.  I appreciate the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can commit as many times you want on one file.